# Alert Box without bringing the application to the foreground

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

i am developing an android application, in  which i have added reminder feature. But , if the application is running in the **background**,say if i am in the **home screen** and the app is running in the background, at time of reminder an **alert box must appear in the screen without bringing the application to the *foreground***.Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

The alert dialog is created with your activity's context so your activity (application) will come in foreground.

Why don't you fire a status bar notification for the same?

Comment: Is there a same app for iPhone? most designers think everything that can be done in iPhone can be replicated in Android and vice versa.

Comment: ya exactly..its there in iphone

Answer (score 0):

Use Service to handle reminder thing and launching reminder message alert box which would be basically an activity or Dialog box.
             But for locked screen, it may or may not display the alert, for that you should use following code in the create method of the Activity

```
// add flag to show activity window if screen is locked.
        Window window = this.getWindow();
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

Above code should be after "super.onCreate(pSavedInstanceState);"

Comment: i have done exactly what you have said.But my problem is to display the alert box without bringing the app to the foreground, if its running in the background.

Answer (score 0):

you should put the reminder code into a service like this

```
public class MyService extends Service {

private Timer timer = new Timer();
private static final long UPDATE_INTERVAL = 3600000;
public MediaPlayer mp;
public String ns =  Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE; 
public NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
public int icon = R.drawable.calendar;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.mail120);
    mNotificationManager  = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);
    //Toast.makeText(this, "Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    timer.cancel();
    //Toast.makeText(this, "Service Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {

    super.onStart(intent, startId);
    _startService(this);


}

public void _startService(final Context context) {
    notified = new ArrayList<String>();
    notified_ergs = "";
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {

             //do some stuff
        }
    },0,UPDATE_INTERVAL);    
}
 }
```

and the register a Broadcastreceiver:

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class MyStartupIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent();
serviceIntent.setAction("[packagename].MyService");
context.startService(serviceIntent);

}
}
```

The told the reciver to start on Boot (in the android Manifest

```
<receiver android:name=".MyStartupIntentReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action
                android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

And now you are able to play a sound, send messages to the notification bar or Toast some messages without starting the Application

Comment: no problem with the code... U can do what you want in the run() void.

Comment: are yu sure that the application doesn't come to the foreground?

Comment: yes, because the context for the toasmessage (or wahtever) is the service, not the Application. This code even runs if the Application is not loaded, because the service is registered to launch on startup.

Answer (score 0):

set the activity lauch mode to singleInstance in the manifest will be fine~